# Oracle to Postgres Migration to_binary_float

Tags: oracle, postgresql

Please suggest Postgres equivalent for `to_binary_float()` Oracle function.

But what confusing me is, two different results are getting displayed for select `cast(1234567898 as real)` in Postgres and `select to_binary_float(1234567898) from dual` in Oracle

Comment: Are you using the same tool to display the results? Different tools might format float values differently. What exactly **are** the values you get? (This might be one of the rare occasions where a screenshot might be suitable)

Comment: I think you are right .I used https://rextester.com to execute oracle query and sqlfiddle.com to execute Postgre

Answer (score 1):

Try `CAST`ing:

```
SELECT CAST (<your_numeric_column> AS real);
```

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your answer: `float` is `double precision`, while Oracle`s `binary_float` is single precision.

Comment: Thank You very much for instant reply .But what confusing me is  , two different  results are getting displayed for select cast(1234567898 as real) in postgre and select to_binary_float(1234567898) from dual in oracle

Comment: I don't have an oracle database to try this unfortunately, so I don't know exactly why you are getting different results. That said, when you execute `select cast(1234567898 as real)` it could be interpreting `1234567898` as "integer" data type rather than "numeric". Try creating a table with a numeric column and using the column to cast to float.